# ASP.Net Session State Issue

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I make use of Session Variable in a if statement.

if(SessionVariable == "AString")
{

Do Something;

}

Problem is the comparison in If works fine if I maintain the session in InState, but doesn't if I use the SQLServer Mode.

The mistake I make is not convert the session variable to string.

Why does it work with InState Sessions and doesn't with SQLServer Sessions?

Comment: Can you provide some more information on this "SessionVariable"?

Answer (score 2):

When you use Sql Server Session State, the variables are serialized. When you pick that variable, you get the *object* type which you must have to be converted. On the other hand if you use *InProc*, the run time knows the underlying type of that variable